# Model Observer Not updating if i'm getting Data From FormRequest

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, observers

i'm using UserObserver and it's working only if i updated My in this way

```
  User::find(1)->update(['name'=> 'vich']);
```

but when i try to do

```
    public function update_user_profile(UpdateProfileRequest $request)
    {
 
        $user = User::find(1)->update($request->validated());
          
    }
```

then the observer will not fire update event but the tow ways are updating without any errors

My Observer

```
    public function updating(User $user)
    {
        dd('99');
    }
```

Comment: Try Log::info('here') instead of dd

Comment: @Aless55 it tried and like dd not working with $request->validated()

Comment: Did you register the observer in your AppServiceProvider?

Comment: @Aless55 i did in EventService Provider it's working on create  the problem is with update

Comment: Double check array structure and also if keys fit table column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the updated values are not 'dirty' meaning they have the same value as in the database and thus not firing any query. Not sure though, but you can try using different values will it fire then?